# XYZ in non-Web Mercator projections

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to use OpenLayers with a XYZ tile server that works with images in non-EPSG:3857 projections. I define a custom tile grid and assign it to the source. My test code is pretty simple:

```js
proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:32628',
  '+proj=utm +zone=28 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
);
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

const tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  extent: [166021.44, 0.0, 534994.66, 9329005.18],
  resolutions: [1441, 720, 360, 180, 90, 45, 22, 11, 5]
});
console.log(tileGrid);
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  }),
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3011/tile/imagery.tif/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png',
      tileGrid: tileGrid,
      projection: "EPSG:32628"
    })
  }),
];
var view = new ol.View({
  center: [323982.0, 1495745.0],
  zoom: 9,
  projection: "EPSG:32628"
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});
```

This doesn't seem to work though: the image doesn't show up on the map, and the stranger part is that OpenLayers requests some unexpected tiles like `4/3/67.png`. I say unexpected because the Y coordinate is greater than 2^4. Does XYZ tiling work in a different way with custom projections?

And does what I'm trying to do even make sense? Note that in my tiling scheme a pixel will be 25 times smaller in height than width because the projection extent is larger along that direction.

Comment: The `{-y`} placeholder does not work with non-standard tilegrids.  You should specify the `origin` in the tilegrid as [166021.44, 0.0] (otherwise it will default to top right) and use a `tileUrlFunction` instead of the `url` option https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html (the example in this version is correct, older versions of the v6 documentation are incorrect).

Comment: Thanks. That still seems to request tiles where y is greated than 2^z. I guess I'm really misinterpreting something.

Comment: XYZ is not standardized on normal mercator: openlayer and leaflets used different XYZ for same coordinate (and mod_tile didn't support it). This was my old post (in gis.SE) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180356/how-to-convert-non-web-mercator-coordinates-to-the-tile-y-x-z-coordinates, so I found  `-y-1`. But I didn't researched further, and things may have changed